# Imported dump grow the table without rows

Tags: postgresql

**TL;DR**

```
my_base=# SELECT *, pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
    , pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX
    , pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
    , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE
  FROM (
  SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-COALESCE(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes FROM (
      SELECT c.oid,nspname AS table_schema, relname AS TABLE_NAME
              , c.reltuples AS row_estimate
              , pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
              , pg_indexes_size(c.oid) AS index_bytes
              , pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_bytes
          FROM pg_class c
          LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
          WHERE relkind = 'r' and relname = 'my_table'
  ) a
) a;
-[ RECORD 1 ]+----------------
oid          | 24116771
table_schema | public
table_name   | my_table
row_estimate | 0
total_bytes  | 13250125824
index_bytes  | 2306334720
toast_bytes  | 8192
table_bytes  | 10943782912
total        | 12 GB
index        | 2199 MB
toast        | 8192 bytes
table        | 10 GB
```

How is that possible ?

**The rest...**

Hello all.

I have to import an huge dump file (12 Go) on my workstation. I created this dump file via the following command :

```
pg_dump -U my_user -d my_base --data-only --table=my_table  > my_table.sql
```

Then I imported the dump file on my workstation :

```
psql -U my_base -f my_table.sql
```

After 1 hour, the import was finish with the following output :

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
















psql:my_table.sql:23308453: ERROR:  Insert or update on table "my_table" violates custom foreign key trigger my_other_table_id_my_table_fk_" 
DETAILS : Key (my_other_table_id = 474804) is not present in my_other_table
CONTEXT : COPY my_table, line 23118758: "... data ..."
  setval  
----------
 23354338
(1 line)
```

From my understanding, the error should just make the import skip on row of the file. After the import, my table have grown, yet it does not contain any row :

```
my_base=# SELECT *, pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
    , pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX
    , pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
    , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE
  FROM (
  SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-COALESCE(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes FROM (
      SELECT c.oid,nspname AS table_schema, relname AS TABLE_NAME
              , c.reltuples AS row_estimate
              , pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
              , pg_indexes_size(c.oid) AS index_bytes
              , pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_bytes
          FROM pg_class c
          LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
          WHERE relkind = 'r' and relname = 'my_table'
  ) a
) a;
-[ RECORD 1 ]+----------------
oid          | 24116771
table_schema | public
table_name   | my_table
row_estimate | 0
total_bytes  | 13250125824
index_bytes  | 2306334720
toast_bytes  | 8192
table_bytes  | 10943782912
total        | 12 GB
index        | 2199 MB
toast        | 8192 bytes
table        | 10 GB
```

How could my table grow, without adding any data ? After several hours (I let my workstation run during the night), I have the following result (I guess the autovacuum worked its magic) :

```
my_base=# SELECT *, pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
    , pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX
    , pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
    , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE
  FROM (
  SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-COALESCE(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes FROM (
      SELECT c.oid,nspname AS table_schema, relname AS TABLE_NAME
              , c.reltuples AS row_estimate
              , pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
              , pg_indexes_size(c.oid) AS index_bytes
              , pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_bytes
          FROM pg_class c
          LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
          WHERE relkind = 'r' and relname = 'my_table'
  ) a
) a;
-[ RECORD 1 ]+----------------
oid          | 24116771
table_schema | public
table_name   | my_table
row_estimate | 0
total_bytes  | 2306359296
index_bytes  | 2306334720
toast_bytes  | 8192
table_bytes  | 16384
total        | 2200 MB
index        | 2199 MB
toast        | 8192 bytes
table        | 16 kB
```

Does someone have any idea what happened here ?

Comment: `Key (my_other_table_id = 474804) is not present in my_other_table` looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: `From my understanding the error should just make the import skip on row of the file ...` Wrong. The FK will cause the whole transaction to be rolled back. Whatever has been imported is still present, but effectively unreachable, and will later be reclaimed by vacuum. (physical compaction is a bit different, IIRC)

Comment: Thanks ! I was not sure how my table could grow without holding any accessible data. I did not know COPY was transactional.

Comment: BTW: the final `setval(...)` will **not** be rolled back; the serial could have gotten a wrong value.